# Change class on first element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a certain amount of `divs` inside another `div`, I need to change the first child class.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

The idea is to change to `item` active the first item

I tried:

```
$("parent").first("item").removeclass("item").addclass("item active");
```

but is not working

Comment: Typo: `$('parent')` should be `$('.parent')`, `('item')` should be `('.item')`, `removeclass()` should be `removeClass()` and `addclass()` should be `addClass()` I ***strongly*** recommend you read the docs: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: Actually, it should be `$('.parent .item').first()`, as `first()` only reduces the set, it doesn't select children

Comment: And you don't need to remove "item". Just `addClass("active")` will do; "item" will still be there.

Comment: `$(".parent .item:first").addClass("item active");
`

Comment: By the way, check your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for the error messages that should have alerted you to the typos ("removeclass" and "addclass").

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have to remove the item class as you only want to add `active` class to the first item, You can try this:

```
$('.parent .item:first-of-type').addClass("active");
```

Comment: I think it's more of TYPO mistake and need to be commented like others did above

Comment: Actually Stack overflow didn't allow me to comment as i must have 50 reputation to be able to comment.

Comment: What is first-of-type?

Comment: It's a css selector and you can see read about it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp